# Use simple js prompt with node to electron app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, electron, prompt

I have an Angular App which is wrapped by an electron. Plus, I used node.js to get MySQL data and give it to the angularJs through electron.
In my project, there is no steady database, so I have to change the database credentials from client side and it should persist for a particular client.

Like I have these default credentials :

```
{ 
    "host":"localhost", 
    "username":"root",
    "password":"123",
    "database":"mydata"
}
```

Now when I move this application to a client, first the application try to connect to db with default credentials and if fails it should ask user for new credetials and it should be saved(maybe as json file!).

I tried prompt from npm, it works fine just with command-line, I want a prompt dialog in electron build app! How can I achieve?

Comment: You can `prompt` in node using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogs) module

Comment: TypeError: dialogs.prompt is not a function! getting this error in RunKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you can use this in your node file.**

**command :**

```
npm install electron-prompt
```

**code :**

```
const prompt = require('electron-prompt');

prompt({
    title: 'Prompt example',
    label: 'URL:',
    value: 'http://example.org',
    inputAttrs: { // attrs to be set if using 'input'
        type: 'url'
    },
    type: 'select', // 'select' or 'input, defaults to 'input'
    selectOptions: { // select options if using 'select' type
        'value 1': 'Display Option 1',
        'value 2': 'Display Option 2',
        'value 3': 'Display Option 3'
    }
})
.then((r) => {
    console.log('result', r); // null if window was closed, or user clicked Cancel
})
.catch(console.error);
```